# How to cast SomeClass to Class<? extends SomeClass >

Tags: java, generics

Have a class: `SomeClass` and its children: `Subclass1`, `Subclass2` and `SubClass3`

Trying to cast `SomeClass` to its subclass based on type

```
SomeClass someClass = getSomeClass();

Class<? extends SomeClass> newChild;

if(someClass.getType() == SubClass1) {
   newChild = (SubClass1) someClass;
} else if(someClass.getType() == SubClass2) {
   newChild = (SubClass2) someClass;
} else if(someClass.getType() == SubClass3) {
   newChild = (SubClass3) someClass;
}
```

Got error:

```
Required type: Class <? extends SomeClass >
Provided: SubClass1
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!!!!!!!!

Comment: A `Class` object is not the same as the corresponding type. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) . What is your actual problem?

Comment: Would like define a general subclass object to accept the casted object from SomeClass,

Comment: The issue is the `== SubClass1`.  You can't just check if something is equal to a type, you have to check if it's equal to a `Class` object, e.g. with `== SubClass1.class`.  (Though `getType()` isn't a usual method and it's not clear what that returns.)

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the `instanceof` operator (e.g. `if (arg instanceof Foo) {...}`)?

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
String x = "hello";
```

`x` is a variable, and this variable can be used to refer to some object instance. However, the type of `x` (`String`) means that `x` must ever and always be referencing either some object whose actual type is either String, or some subtype thereof, or, `null`. You can't assign, say, a reference to an `Integer` or `InputStream` object to it.

this:

```
Class<? extends String> x = ...;
```

is quite different. Each class in java has 1 object that represents it. Just like the notion of trees is not itself a tree, so is the notion of strings not itself a string. it is a Class, and classes and strings are as different as guns and grandmas.

Thus, `Class<? extends SomeClass>` does not represent a someclass instance at all. It represents some class **itself** - and that class must be SomeClass or some subtype thereof.

Thus, when you write:

```
newChild = (SubClass1) someClass;
```

that makes no sense at all - you are casting `someClass` to `(SubClass1)` which means you're saying that the `someClass` expression is referencing __an instance of SubClass1`, and just like that tree in your back garden is not, in any way or form, the same thing as the concept of tree, so is this line utter gobbledygook.

It sounds like you simply want `newChild` to hold a reference to an actual instance.

In which case you're very confused - that is extremely trivial. Just.. do it.

```
SomeClass someClass = new SubClass1();
```

That's entirely legal.

If you have:

```
class SomeClass {}

class SubClass1 extends SomeClass {}
```

That means that **all instances of SubClass1 are also SomeClass**. You can't not have that be the case. Think of it this way: All Toyota Camries are Cars. `Car car = new ToyotaCamry();` makes perfect sense. There is no need or point to an if block here, at all.